# Is read guaranteed to return as soon as data is available?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I want to implement a simple notification protocol using TCP sockets. The server will write a byte to a socket to notify the client, and the client reads from the socket, waiting until some data arrives, at which point it can return from the `read` call and perform some work.

```
while (1) {
    /* Wait for any notifications */
    char buf[32];
    if (read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf)) <= 0) {
        break;
    }

    /* Received notification */
    do_work();
}
```

My question is, is `read` guaranteed to return as soon as **any** data is available to read, or is the kernel allowed to keep waiting until some condition is met (e.g. some minimum number of bytes received, not necessarily the `count` which I pass into `read`) before it returns from the `read` call? If the latter is true, is there a flag that will disable that behavior?

I am aware that I could use the `O_NONBLOCK` flag and call `read` in a loop, but the purpose of this is to use as little CPU time as possible.

Comment: Read about [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)

Comment: I don't think it's specified, but I've never heard of a TCP implementation that waits. But how would you tell the difference between the kernel waiting and the packet being delayed in the network?

Comment: @Barmar That's true, I just wanted to know if the kernel would add any additional latency.

Comment: I don't think it's any different from any other stream. Is a read from the terminal guaranteed to return as soon as the user presses Return?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `poll()` and `select()` simply tell the caller whether `read()` would return immediately. So if the kernel is delaying the data, I'd expect it to delay the `poll()` result as well.

Comment: I know that, but like you I don't believe that the kernel would *delay* data

Comment: TCP will sometimes delay *sending* data so it can combine them in a single segment (this is part of the Nagle algorithm). There's little reason to delay making incoming data available to `read()`.

Comment: You should probably ask another question detailing the plans of your protocol. There are a lot of easy mistakes you can make that will cause latency in TCP and some very simple changes to the protocol can avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple implicit questions here:

> Is `read` guaranteed to return immediately or shortly after a relevant event?

No. The kernel is technically allowed to make you wait as long as it wants.

In practice, it'll return immediately (modulo rescheduling delays).

This is true for `poll` and `O_NONBLOCK` as well. Linux is not a realtime OS, and offers no hard timing guarantees, just its best effort.

> Is `read` allowed to wait indefinitely for multiple bytes to become available?

No, this would cause deadlocks. `read` needs to be able to return with a single byte, even if there are no guarantees about when it will do so.

In practice, Linux makes the same effort for 1 byte as it does for 1,048,576.

> Is sending a single byte on a socket a practical way of waking up a remote process as soon as possible?

Yes, your example is perfectly fine.